# how to read multiple gpio pin at a time and perform some task in raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

As per my project i am already interfacing rotary encoder with raspberry with interrupt callback method and interface some output depending on that.But i am stuck to read 3 GPIO pin as i am using them as an input and read signal coming from another controller as 3.3v and 0v(for 1,0).As my complete code is so long ,i created demo of my code and providing same below.

```
import pigpio
import tkinter as tk
import time
class decoder: "for my interrupt event "
    ######
   #######
if __name__=="__main__":
    pi.set_mode(5,pigpio.INPUT)
    pi.set_mode(6, pigpio.INPUT)
    pi.set_mode(13, pigpio.INPUT)
    pi.set_pull_up_down(5,pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
    pi.set_pull_up_down(6, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
    pi.set_pull_up_down(13, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
    def callback(*arg):
        ####
    def blinklevel1():
        ******
    def blinklevel2():
        ******
    def blinklevel3():
        ********
    decoder=rotary_encoder.decoder(pi,22,23,callback())
    root=tk.TK()
    L1=tk.Label(root,text="1st level on")
    L1.pack()
    L2=tk.Label(root,text="2nd level on")
    L2.pack()
    L3=tk.Label(root,text="3rd level on")
    L3.pack()
    if pi.read(5)==1 and pi.read(6)==0 and pi.read(13)==0:
        blinklevel1()
    if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 1 and pi.read(13) == 0:
        blinklevel2()
    if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 0 and pi.read(13) == 1:
        blinklevel3()
    root.mainloop()
    pi.stop()
```

i am particularly facing issue with below part of complete code:

```
if pi.read(5)==1 and pi.read(6)==0 and pi.read(13)==0:
       blinklevel1()
   if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 1 and pi.read(13) == 0:
       blinklevel2()
   if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 0 and pi.read(13) == 1:
       blinklevel3()
```

This part of code is running fine if i created another program and put this like..

```
try:
  while True:
     if pi.read(5)==1 and pi.read(6)==0 and pi.read(13)==0:
        blinklevel1()
     if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 1 and pi.read(13) == 0:
        blinklevel2()
     if pi.read(5) == 1 and pi.read(6) == 0 and pi.read(13) == 1:
        blinklevel3()
finally:
....
```

But i can't use while True concept in my project code as already tkinter loop is running .

Comment: Use `after()` instead of while loop.  Also should `pi.read(5)` , `pi.read(6)` and `pi.read(13)` be executed once in each iteration.

Comment: @acw1668, by reading (5,6,13) gpio pin mode will be select such as if it is (0 0 1) then blinklevel1 will be selected,and (0 1 0) then blinklevel 2 and so on upto (1 1 1).

Comment: What I mean is that: `v5, v6, v13 = pi.read(5), pi.read(6), pi.read(13)`, then use `v5`, `v6` and `v13` in the if statements.